# Oracle - Regex Replace ([0-9]{1,}\.[0-9]{1,}) with 0.00 but not surround by <qCom></qCom>

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, oracle11g

I have to replace values inside XML tags to make value zero

Example:

```
<cProd>7898132541927</cProd>
<cEAN>7898132541927</cEAN>
<uCom>UN</uCom>
<qCom>12.0000</qCom>
<vUnCom>47.6600000000</vUnCom>
<vProd>571.92</vProd>
<cEANTrib>7898132541927</cEANTrib>
<uTrib>UN</uTrib>
<qTrib>12.0000</qTrib>
<vUnTrib>47.6600000000</vUnTrib>
<indTot>1</indTot>
```

The result i need:

```
<cProd>7898132541927</cProd>
<cEAN>7898132541927</cEAN>
<uCom>UN</uCom>
<qCom>12.0000</qCom>
<vUnCom>0.00</vUnCom>
<vProd>0.00</vProd>
<cEANTrib>7898132541927</cEANTrib>
<uTrib>UN</uTrib>
<qTrib>12.0000</qTrib>
<vUnTrib>0.00</vUnTrib>
<indTot>1</indTot>
```

I have to use Oracle, than i write the right script:

```
SELECT
REGEXP_REPLACE('
    <cProd>7898132541927</cProd>
    <cEAN>7898132541927</cEAN>
    <uCom>UN</uCom>
    <qCom>12.0000</qCom>
    <vUnCom>47.6600000000</vUnCom>
    <vProd>571.92</vProd>
    <cEANTrib>7898132541927</cEANTrib>
    <uTrib>UN</uTrib>
    <qTrib>12.0000</qTrib>
    <vUnTrib>47.6600000000</vUnTrib>
    <indTot>1</indTot>
'
, '([0-9]{1,}\.[0-9]{1,})(?!</qCom|?!</qTrib)'
, '0.00') RES
FROM DUAL
;
```

The Regex `([0-9]{1,}\.[0-9]{1,})` works, but in the tag `qCom` and `qTrib`, i have to make an exception in the regex

Someone could help.
Tks

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't get this to work with a negative lookbehind (`(?<!)`), but I noticed the only numbers you want to set to 0.00 are those that are inside tags beginning with `v`.

Using a positive lookbehind (`(?<=`) this regex pattern seems to work:

```
'(?<=<v[A-Za-z]+>)([0-9]+\.[0-9]+)'
```

Used on the example you gave, this will yield

```
<cProd>7898132541927</cProd>
<cEAN>7898132541927</cEAN>
<uCom>UN</uCom>
<qCom>12.0000</qCom>
<vUnCom>0.00</vUnCom>
<vProd>0.00</vProd>
<cEANTrib>7898132541927</cEANTrib>
<uTrib>UN</uTrib>
<qTrib>12.0000</qTrib>
<vUnTrib>0.00</vUnTrib>
<indTot>1</indTot>
```

Regex details:

```
'(?<='           Assert that the regex below can be matched, with the match ending at this position (positive lookbehind)
   '<v'          Match the characters “<v” literally
   '[A-Za-z]'    Match a single character present in the list below
                 A character in the range between “A” and “Z”
                 A character in the range between “a” and “z”
      '+'        Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
   '>'           Match the character “>” literally
')' 
'('              Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 1
   '[0-9]'       Match a single character in the range between “0” and “9”
      '+'        Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
   '\.'          Match the character “.” literally
   '[0-9]'       Match a single character in the range between “0” and “9”
      '+'        Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
')'
```

Comment: @akaAndyDaSilva Glad it put you in the right direction. Just curious though.. Isn't `{1,}+` a bit of overkill, since `+` also means 'one or more'

Comment: You right `SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(' <cProd>7898132541927</cProd> <cEAN>7898132541927</cEAN> <uCom>UN</uCom> <qCom>12.0000</qCom> <vUnCom>47.6600000000</vUnCom> <vProd>571.92</vProd> <cEANTrib>7898132541927</cEANTrib> <uTrib>UN</uTrib> <qTrib>12.0000</qTrib> <vUnTrib>47.6600000000</vUnTrib> <indTot>1</indTot> ', '(?<v[A-Za-z]+>)([0-9]+\.[0-9]+)' , '\10.00') RES FROM DUAL ;`

Answer (score 0):

Given that Oracle already has built-in XML functionality to do this - why not use that?

e.g. with XQuery update (assumes valid XML document)

```
WITH table_name (xmlvalue)
     AS (SELECT XMLTYPE (
'<Document>
  <cProd>7898132541927</cProd>
  <cEAN>7898132541927</cEAN>
  <uCom>UN</uCom>
  <qCom>12.0000</qCom>
  <vUnCom>47.6600000000</vUnCom>
  <vProd>571.92</vProd>
  <cEANTrib>7898132541927</cEANTrib>
  <uTrib>UN</uTrib>
  <qTrib>12.0000</qTrib>
  <vUnTrib>47.6600000000</vUnTrib>
  <indTot>1</indTot>
</Document>') FROM DUAL)
SELECT XMLQUERY (
         'copy $new := $old 
          modify (
             for $node in $new/Document/node()[matches(.,"[0-9]+\.[0-9]+") and not(local-name()=("qCom","qTrib"))] 
             return replace value of node $node with "0.00") 
          return $new'
          PASSING 
             xmlvalue AS "old"
          RETURNING CONTENT) result
FROM   table_name;

<Document>
  <cProd>7898132541927</cProd>
  <cEAN>7898132541927</cEAN>
  <uCom>UN</uCom>
  <qCom>12.0000</qCom>
  <vUnCom>0.00</vUnCom>
  <vProd>0.00</vProd>
  <cEANTrib>7898132541927</cEANTrib>
  <uTrib>UN</uTrib>
  <qTrib>12.0000</qTrib>
  <vUnTrib>0.00</vUnTrib>
  <indTot>1</indTot>
</Document>
```